# JSON Get the name of dynamically changing key with PHP

Tags: php, json, foreach

I am having trouble getting the name of a dynamic key from a JSON string.
I am using PHP

This is a sample of the JSON

```
{
"_text": "this is a test",
"entities": {
    "dynamic_key": [
        {
            "confidence": 0.99,
            "value": "thi is the answer"
        }
    ]
},
"msg_id": "1234532123"
}
```

I am using foreach to go trough the json key and get the values

```
foreach ($json as $obj) {
        $search_term = $obj->_text;
        $msg_id = $obj->msg_id;
    }
```

But I am not sure how to get the value of the "dynamic_key" which changes every time, and because of that I also cannot get the values of "confidence and value" keys.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

**Followed @Dimi, solution.** This is what I ended up with

```
$data=json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($data['entities'] as $key=>$val)
{
echo "Entity: $key";

    foreach ($data['entities'] as $keys){
        $conf = $keys[0]['confidence'];
        $answer = $keys[0]['value'];
        echo "conf: $conf, answ: $answer";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide a couple more examples?
Or try this code and let us know if it breaks

```
<?php

$json='{
"_text": "this is a test",
"entities": {
    "dynamic_key": [
        {
            "confidence": 0.99,
            "value": "thi is the answer"
        }
    ]
},
"msg_id": "1234532123"
}';


$data=json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($data['entities'] as $key=>$val)
{
echo "VALUE IS $key\n values are ";
var_dump($val);


}
```

Comment: Now the is assigned to the $key, but how would I assign the other key values to a variable? Do I have to do a nested foreach, or I have to do something else?

Comment: @lStoilov can you add more keys and an example of how you want data to look like when you are done?

Comment: Just did another foreach. Will update my answer with the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using the data you've shown, there doesn't seem to be an array for the starting JSON.

But with that data the following will use `foreach` to both fetch the key and the data and then another sub-loop to fetch the `confidence`value...

```
$search_term = $json->_text;
$msg_id = $json->msg_id;
foreach ( $json->entities as $key => $entities )    {
    echo $key.PHP_EOL;
    foreach ( $entities as $entity) {
        echo $entity->confidence.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you decode the JSON as an array and if the dynamic key is the only key under `entities`, then:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$dynamic = current($array['entities']);
$confidence = $dynamic['confidence'];
$value = $dynamic['value'];
```

Or shorter:

```
$confidence = current($array['entities'])['confidence'];
```

You can probably use `reset`, `current` and maybe `array_pop` etc.